# .htaccess redirect index.php / index only if directly after root URL?

Tags: .htaccess

Here is a part of my .htaccess file,

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

I understand what it does, it will search and if the end part ends in `index` it will remove it.

But I have now noticed that if I type into the address bar `http://example.com/index/index`, I get an internal server error which is never good, and would like it to return a 404, as indeed the directory `index` does not or will not exist.

How can I change the rule to only search if the address is `http://example.com/index` and then to rewrite?

Thanks

Comment: You're trying to remove `index` or `index.php` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*?)/index\.php[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```